# How can I solve the railway line planning problem?

Tags: cplex, opl

I’m writing my thesis about the line planning problem for railway passenger transport. I want to look at different methods that calculate robustness in a railway network. As I am not experienced with OPL I encounter some problems with solving the model. My supervisor can’t help me I am desperately looking for someone who can help me get my model right. The model should determine which lines to imply, together with the frequency and the number of carriages of the trains, while keeping costs at a minimum.

I have the following two problems: 
I have a set of edges (E), and a set of potential lines (L). How can I tell OPL that for instance, line 1 consists of edges 1 and 2. I find it difficult to link these variables.

I am working with a binary decision variable x[L][F][C] that represents the line, frequency of the line and the number of carriages respectively. How do I tell the model that a value is only multiplied by the value of F. For instance the 3rd constraint, I want to multiply the values of F and C with the capC.

```
int nv = ...;
range V = 1..nv;            //set of stations.

int ne =...;
range E =1..ne;                 //set of edges.

int nf = ...;
range F = 1..nf;            //set of possible frequencies.

int nc = ...;   
range C = 1..nc;            //set of possible carriages.

int nl = ...;
range L = 1..nl;            //set of potential lines.

//Parameters

int capC = ...;             //Capacity per carriage

int w[L] = ...;             //cost for using line l

int fmin[E] = ...;          //min freq per line l 

int fmax[E] = ...;          //max freq per line l

int h[E] = ...;             //Demand edge e

//Decision variable

dvar boolean x[L][F][C];                        

//Objective function
minimize sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) w[l] * x[l][f][c]; 

//Constraints

subject to {
forall (e in E)
  sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) x[l][f][c] >= fmin[e];        //Min edge freq

forall (e in E)
  sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) x[l][f][c] <= fmax[e];        //Max edge freq 

forall (e in E)
  sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) x[l][f][c] * capC >= h[e];  //Transfer all passengers

forall (l in L)
  sum(f in F, c in C) x[l][f][c] <= 1;              //Per line at most 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding "I want to multiply the values of F and C with the capC", have you tried to turn

```
forall (e in E) sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) x[l][f][c] * capC >= h[e]; //Transfer all passengers
```

into

```
forall (e in E) sum(l in L, f in F, c in C) f*c*x[l][f][c] * capC >= h[e]; //Transfer all passengers
```

?